# Spring Boot accessing JSP directly from URL works from within IDE but does not work after packaging as WAR

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, jsp, war

I have [a spring boot project based on Maven](https://github.com/springstartertest).

When I Run/ Debug this project from within the VS code, and check the URL `http://localhost:8080/employeeView.jsp`, I get the desired results.

But when I try to package the project into a .war using `mvn package`, run it on an external apache tomcat, and check the corresponding URL (`http://localhost:8080/NAME_OF_WAR/employeeView.jsp`), it gives a 404 not found error. Why?

Comment: What is the name of the war file?

Comment: Not sure how that is relevant.. 
but the name of the war file that gets created is "spring-boot-servlet-jsp-spring-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war"

Comment: I understand that I want to leverage the advantages of quick setup / quick development features that spring boot provied and still be able to deploy it to a WAR file where my app will sit on a single Container server alongwith other Apps..

In this instance, a Single tomcat server which has port 80 opened and i would want all my apps to be part of this tomcat server.

Comment: @Shoaeb The name of the war file might be relevant if you didn't provide a context configuration. Also you should post the server logs to see if it's started correctly.

Comment: @Roman, Ah I see why the name of the war might be relevant. I have edited my question.
Thanks

Comment: Why are you trying to access a JSP file directly? You are not supposed to do that with a Spring application (which uses the MVC architecture).

Comment: Having the project on an open linked repository is not sufficient for questions on Stack Overflow. Please read [mre]. We *must* have enough code to demonstrate the problem *in the question itself*.

Answer (score 1):

> But when I try to do the same after packaging using mvn package the project into a war and running it on an external apache tomcat , I get Not found error.

I do not see in [your project](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Acrystaldeveloper2017%2Fspringstartertest%20SpringBootServletInitializer&type=code) a [`SpringBootServletInitializer`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/web/servlet/support/SpringBootServletInitializer.html), which should be essential because it allows the servlet container to run your application by bootstrapping it via code, rather than using the web.xml descriptor file: if you are deploying your Spring Boot application as a WAR file to an external servlet container like Apache Tomcat, you will need a class that extends `SpringBootServletInitializer`.

Something like:

```java
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(YourApplication.class);
    }

}
```

Plus, as [seen here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-jsp#view-resolver-configuration), the JSP files should be under the `${project.basedir}/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/` directory.

The `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/` directory is the standard location for resources that need to be protected from direct access (which typically includes JSP files), as the servlet specification restricts direct access to files under the `WEB-INF/` directory.

Make sure your `src/main/resources/application.properties` (or `src/main/resources/application.yml`) has the correct settings for view resolution:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

This tells Spring Boot to look for views in the `/WEB-INF/jsp/` directory (with `.jsp` extension).
The prefix and suffix properties are used to generate the real view path based on the view name returned by the controller.

For example, if your controller returns "`employeeView`" as the view name, Spring will use the prefix and suffix to resolve that to `/WEB-INF/jsp/employeeView.jsp`.

So your project structure should be something like:

```
.
├── src
│   ├── main
│   │   ├── java
│   │   │   └── com
│   │   │       └── yourpackage
│   │   │           └── YourApplication.java
│   │   ├── resources
│   │   │   └── application.properties
│   │   └── webapp
│   │       └── WEB-INF
│   │           └── jsp
│   │               └── employeeView.jsp
└── pom.xml
```

---

> My concern is that the same project works fine in a Dev environment and does not when Packaged into a war. What Change should be added in the packaging that it behaves the same way it is behaving for Dev env

The discrepancy you're seeing is likely due to differences in how embedded servers (like the one used when you run the application from your IDE or using `mvn spring-boot:run`) and standalone servers (like the Apache Tomcat you're deploying your WAR to) handle resource loading.

When using an embedded server, Spring Boot uses its [own resource loading logic](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-core/resource-loading.html), which includes several locations under `src/main/resources` in the classpath, including `/META-INF/resources/`, where you currently have your JSP.
However, standalone servers like Apache Tomcat use the Servlet API's resource loading logic, which does not include `/META-INF/resources/` in the classpath for JSP files.

There's no direct way to make Tomcat load JSP files from `/META-INF/resources/` like the embedded server does, because this behavior is hard-coded in the Servlet specification, which Tomcat follows. JSPs are expected to be located under `/WEB-INF/`.

---

Plus, in a [Spring MVC framework](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html), you would not directly access JSP files via the URL.
Instead, a common pattern is for the client to interact with a controller, which then decides which view (such as a JSP) to show based on the request.

For example, you might have a controller method that looks like this:

```java
@Controller
public class EmployeeController {

    @GetMapping("/employeeView")
    public String showEmployeeView() {
        // You might add some attributes to the model here...
        return "employeeView"; // Spring will use the view resolver settings to find the JSP
    }
}
```

Then, if your `spring.mvc.view.prefix` is `/WEB-INF/jsp/` and `spring.mvc.view.suffix` is `.jsp` (specified in your `application.properties`), Spring will use those to find the view at `/WEB-INF/jsp/employeeView.jsp`.

You would then access the view by going to `http://localhost:8080/employeeView` (when running locally), not `http://localhost:8080/employeeView.jsp`.

This pattern allows you to include any necessary server-side processing before the view is returned, and it helps to hide the implementation details of your views (such as their locations and the technologies used to create them) from the client.
It is also more in line with the principles of MVC architecture, where the controller handles user interactions and decides which view to display.

Comment: I agree with the above and know that this is not the standard practice / Convention to keep the JSP files. However, My concern is that the same project works fine in a Dev environment and does not when Packaged into a war. What Change should be added in the packaging that it behaves the same way it is behaving for Dev env.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of servlets, I would use Spring controllers.

There is no reason why the jsp should not be picked up from there.
It's quite common to have a index.jsp or index.html.

I use eclipse and it works fine when I do Run on Server or when I take the war file and manually put it into tomcat webapps. You can even right click on your main class java file and use Run as Spring Boot Application.

Another issue could be you are targeting different server versions from your IDE vs when you deploy as war. This might cause an issue if one of them is tomcat 10 and the other is a lower version, because of breaking changes in the servlet API.

Comment: When you say "when I take the war file and manually put it into tomcat webapps", do you export using eclipse or do "mvn package" to generate the WAR.. ?

Comment: I meant using mvn clean package take the war file from generated  target folder. The export wizard has too many manual steps

Comment: I added a line " You can even right click on your main class java file and use Run as Spring Boot Application." I hope you dont remove your git repository. Its a good refernce even though some things are a bit different.

Comment: Can you share your code snippet that is working for  you on both embedded tomcat and external tomcat ?

Comment: No real change in your code other than the snippets I shared above. Note: server.servlet.context-path=/spring-boot-servlet-jsp-spring. Because that matches the artifactId. Which means if you use this setup and run the urls will be http://localhost:8080/spring-boot-servlet-jsp-spring

Comment: It works all the ways its supposed to. By the way you have committed the target folder. Remove it from there. Use a .gitignore. In eclipse Sometimes it also helps to do this. Right click on project. Do a F5(Refresh). Then Right click do a Maven Update. Then lastly from Project menu to do a clean before running the app.

Comment: Not sure if this could be the difference- I am not using springtools. Just using the eclipse JEE edition.

Comment: Small correction. I am using a recent eclipse.- Version: 2023-03 (4.27.0) Build id: 20230309-1520. I do have spring tools manually installed from market place. Maybe that will help.